# Float left and right

Tags: css, css-float

this problem has been bothering me for some time. So I have created some visual descriptions of my problem

First here is my HTML structure I have 6 divs.. the first 3 float left and the last 3 float right. The last image shows the result I want but can't seem to get. Can someone out there help me here

EDIT// Sorry heres my HTML and CSS

```
<style>
    .left { float:left; }
    .right { float:right; }
</style>
<div id="container">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I Cant do a left right left right left right option because Im getting my data from PHP via a Query to my database.. first query goes left second query goes right.... thanks a bunch

/EDIT

[image: This is a mocukup of my HTML structure]

My floats result in this

[image: this is my current result]

This is what I want

[image: I want this]

Comment: +1 for the nice images, -1 for no markup or CSS at all in the question!

Comment: I have updated my question with some html.. I cant do one left then one right.. because of the way my data is returned.

Comment: Let me get this straight. There are always exactly six `div`s. You need to support >=IE7 and all modern browsers. Your HTML is what you posted in the question, and you cannot change it. Is all of that true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `column-count` property for this. Write like this:

```
.parent{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 50%;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50%;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50%;
}
.parent div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;  
    margin:10px;
}
.left{
    background:red;
}
.right{
    background:green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/UaFFP/6/

Comment: It's useful to mention browser support whenever you answer with CSS3 columns: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn. For example, this won't work in IE9, which many people need to support.

Comment: This was exactly what I was lookin for. But I do need support for ie7 and up. So its not entirely usefull.. but you got the idea right as most ppl didnt. So thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Float one left , one right, and give first the clear:both property

```
<div class="left clear"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left clear"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

css

```
.left {float:left}
.right {float:right}
.clear {clear:both}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WCzaN/)

Answer (score 7):

Add the first left div, then the first right div and after them add `<br style="clear:both">` and repeat the procedure.

**Edit**: Here's an updated answer:

```
<div style="border:1px solid blue;float:right;height:100px;width:100px;clear:right;"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;height:100px;width:100px;clear:left;"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;float:right;height:100px;width:100px;clear:right;"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;height:100px;width:100px;clear:left;"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;float:right;height:100px;width:100px;clear:right;"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;height:100px;width:100px;clear:left;"></div>
```

Comment: Why? You can make the **<br>** have absolutely no visual representation.

Comment: Im working on a project where the only thig I have access to is the CSS files.. everyting else is offlimits

Comment: Having to change the structural code to satisfy the presentation defeats the entire purpose of CSS. This is not a good solution, despite the fact that it works.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have another div in the middle of them. Then use this chronological order:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Or if you don't, just add another div that provide a style `clear:both` to it.

Comment: Having to manipulate the order of elements is not a good solution either.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">

.parent {width:50px; border:1px solid red;}

.left {float:left; }

.right{float:right;}

.child{height:50px;width:50px;border:solid 1px green;margin:0 0 10px 0;}

</style>

<body>

<div class="left parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="right parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Mind it would be odd not to have a central DIV, if that is a case float the parent DIVs left, at say widths of 20% 60% 20%.

Comment: I woud have done this but Im instructed not to touch the HTML, I can only change the CSS

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.leftcolums {
  float: left;
}

.rightcolums {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcolums">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left">2</div>
  <div class="left">3</div>
</div>
<div class="rightcolums">
  <div class="right">4</div>
  <div class="right">5</div>
  <div class="right">6</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">7</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`column-count` is already widely supported - http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn
So if old browsers doesn't bother you consider using it.

Comment: And what do you do with it (to solve the OP's problem)?

Comment: I to would like to know, 3 years later :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the :nth-child selector and clearing after 2 divs:

```
​div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nSDcb/)

Otherwise use this fairly hacky method, which requires no additional markup:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
div:nth-child(n) {
    clear: both;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -50px; //match this to the div height
}
```

​
[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nSDcb/1/)

Comment: I've tried modding it a bit but cant seem to get it right. Here is where Im at, I cant touch the HTML.. this is fixed.. I can only work with the CSS [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nSDcb/)