# CSS Float Left and then Right

Tags: css

I have a problem with the floating. I'll try to explain my problem. What I have is 6 menu bars I want to float. 3 on the left and 3 on the right. However I want the ones on the right to come after the 3 on the left. As in they are no higher than the bottom of the last left one. Similar to the picture someone else had (Credit goes to the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994515/float-left-and-right)

[image]

However instead I am getting all of the bars in the same rows like so.

[image]

I have provided ALL CSS proporties below. Can anyone figure out why I can't get it the way I wanted? (The bar-groups go inside the gameplay-info-content)

```
#gameplay-info-content {width: 688px;}
#bar-group-left {float: left; margin: 8px;}
#bar-group-right {float: right; margin: 8px;}
```

Comment: WHen you float something, those somethings are removed from all kinds of sizing/positioning calculations. if you want your "right" elements to be "below" the "left" elements, you'll have to do something like put a `<br style="clear: both">` in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="leftcolums">
    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="left">2</div>
    <div class="left">3</div>    
</div>

//If you want to achieve the first image add a div with class clear below
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="rightcolums">
    <div class="right">4</div>
    <div class="right">5</div>
    <div class="right">6</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

STYLES:

```
.leftcolums{float:left;}
.rightcolums{float:right;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Same problem as last time :(

Comment: You want to achieve the first picture or the second one?